# Vagrant tries to use VirtualBox although I specified libvirt

Tags: vagrant

I would like to use a virtual box with Vagrant using `KVM` and `libvirt` on my Fedora 25 system. This has worked already with Fedora 24. When I try to start the machine, it seems to ignore the `--provider libvirt` flag and still uses VirtualBox:

```
$ vagrant up --provider libvirt
The provider 'virtualbox' that was requested to back the machine
'default' is reporting that it isn't usable on this system. The
reason is shown below:

Vagrant could not detect VirtualBox! Make sure VirtualBox is properly installed.
Vagrant uses the `VBoxManage` binary that ships with VirtualBox, and requires
this to be available on the PATH. If VirtualBox is installed, please find the
`VBoxManage` binary and add it to the PATH environmental variable.
```

How can I get it to use KVM?

---

My `Vagrantfile` is just this:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install devscripts
  SHELL
end
```

Comment: Could you post your vagrantfile ? My first guess would be that the config file is explicitly specifying Virtualbox as the provider something like that:
' config.vm.provider :virtualbox'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the things I did not say: I have used VirtualBox in the past for this project. Therefore in the `.vagrant` folder, there are some remnants from that. Now Vagrant correctly uses that last provider that I have used and will not change because the state in the machine would be lost.

Removing the `.vagrant` folder did the correct thing, Vagrant tried to download the virtual machine image for `libvirt`. However, there seem to be no more `libvirt` images on the Atlas, therefore one needs to use the `mutate` plugin to convert it.